# flask session doesn't persist when invoke the call from c# mvc web application

Tags: python, c#, flask, web-applications, session-state

I wrote a web service in python flask.
In my code I have flask session object and it looks good.

Here is a short example how my python code look like-

```
@app.route('/api/simpleTry', methods=['GET'])
def api_simple():
    user_id = request.args['id']
    sentence = request.args['sentence']

    if 'user_id' not in session.keys():
        session['user_id'] = user_id
    return jsonify("hello")
app.run()
```

when I invoke the service through 'crome' explorer it works good, the session persist and when I 2 open 2 clients (1- crome, 2-incognito) I can see that each one of them has a separate session.

in addition,
I have a C# mvc web application that act as my client and over there I call the python flask service I wrote.

```
address = "http://localhost:5000/api/simpleTry?id=" + userId + "&sentence=" + sentence;
using (var w = new WebClient())
{
     json_data = w.DownloadString(address);
     ...
}
```

The code works well. **but**, as opposed to 'crome', when sending the request from c#, the session in python **does not** persist and create a new session for each request.

I guess I should send something from C# to the service in order to use the existing session, but I don't what and how.

Comment: did you store & send back the `session` cookie returned in the header?

Answer (score 0):

Flask sessions uses cookies to communicate session information between the client & server. When you used a browser, the browser is the client & automatically sends the cookies back to the server. When you use a C# client, I'm not sure if it does that for you automatically. You may have to read the `session` cookie from the header & send it along with subsequent requests.

From the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/?highlight=session#sessions): `This is implemented on top of cookies for you and signs the cookies cryptographically`

Comment: Thank you!  I understood that. I just don't have any idae how should I do it in c#